# Provider Factory Command Timeout - how to set it

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am having a problem with a SQL server query giving a timeout error. I read about setting the timeout value of the command object but in my DAL, I do not see how to do that. Here is how I create the command object

```
Public Sub Init()
    If ConnString = "" Then
        Select Case ConnStringID
            Case "SQL"
                ConnString = theSQLConnectionString
                Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"
            Case "Access"
                ConnString = theAccessConnectionString
                Provider = "System.Data.OleDb"
        End Select
    End If
    If Conn Is Nothing Then
        PFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Provider)
        Conn = PFactory.CreateConnection
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConnString
        Cmd = PFactory.CreateCommand
    End If
End Sub
```

I do not see a property of Cmd for CommandTim

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, for example:

```
Cmd.CommandTimeout = 30 'Seconds
```

If this does not autocomplete, make sure Cmd is declared as type `DbCommand`.